# ionic 3 - Image resizing for android ios apps

Tags: android, ios, angular, typescript, ionic3

I am developing cross platform application using ionic3/angular. In that want to resize the images based on the android and IOS device sizes (Is it possible to do this using CSS). Can you please let me know how to achieve this in Ionic 3.

Thanks